# Know the Common Name from an SSL Certificate

Tags: objective-c

I'm very new to this filed...I want to check the CN in a SSL Server Certificate...how can I achieve that? I'm Using NSURLConnection delegate methods canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace and didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge.

Answer (score 5):

Use the 2 delegate methods below and include the Security.framework, and replace KNOWN-COMMON-NAME with whatever your cert common name is.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
    SecTrustRef trustRef = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
    SecTrustEvaluate(trustRef, NULL);
    CFIndex count = SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trustRef); 
    BOOL trust = NO;
    if(count > 0){
        SecCertificateRef certRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trustRef, 0);
        CFStringRef certSummary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certRef);
        NSString* certSummaryNs = (NSString*)certSummary;
        if([certSummaryNs isEqualToString:@"KNOWN-COMMON-NAME"]){ // split host n
            trust = YES;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Certificate name does not have required common name");
        }
        CFRelease(certSummary);
    }
    if(trust){
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }else{
        [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
[challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}
```

Comment: Why SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary instead of SecCertificateCopyCommonName?

Comment: coz SecCertificateCopyCommonName is not available in iOS (only in OSX)

Answer (score 2):

Since **iOS 10.3** there has been a [function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1394814-seccertificatecopycommonname?language=objc) available in Security framework:

```
CFStringRef commonNameRef = NULL;

// Check if function is available (iOS 10.3 and above)
if (SecCertificateCopyCommonName) {
    SecCertificateCopyCommonName(certificateRef, &commonNameRef);
}

NSString *commonName = CFBridgingRelease(commonNameRef);
```